# BCC Character Length Limit?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm trying to populate a BCC field with email addresses from a LotusScript agent that I run from a view. I noticed that once my email list gets to 255 characters or more, the list loses data. I'm aware that Notes has a maximum number of characters allowed for text fields, but I noticed that you can manually type more than 254 characters in the BCC field just fine.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a different way I can do this? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the BCC field as an **array** if you have more then one email. If you put all in one string Notes takes it as one email address and shortens it to 254 characters.

You can easily change your string to an array of strings if you use **split()**:

```
doc.ReplaceItemValue("BlindCopyTo", split(YourEmailAddresses, ",")
```

assuming you delimited email addresses with ",".

If you manually type more then 255 characters in Memo document's BCC field then it automatically gets changed to a text list because the EnterBlindCopyTo field has the option "Allow multiple values" with comma as separator. That's why it works there.

Comment: Note that there is still a limit -- 32KB for summary fields, of which this is one.